# Calculate binary entropy loss using a function in pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a problem about calculating binary cross entropy. The way I know that works out in pytorch is:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
def lossfunc():
    return F.binary_cross_entropy

criterion = lossFunc()
input = torch.randn((3, 2), requires_grad=True)
target = torch.rand((3, 2), requires_grad=False)
loss = criterion(torch.sigmoid(input),target)
```

But how to complete the lossfunc() in such way, because I don't know how to pass the arguments to the function:

```
#the function that add sigmoid to input and calculate the binary cross entropy loss
def lossfunc():
   return

criterion = lossFunc()
input = torch.randn((3, 2), requires_grad=True)
target = torch.rand((3, 2), requires_grad=False)
loss = criterion(input,target)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the `nn` api with the functional `F` api. In functional api, loss function `F.binary_cross_entropy` can be used as a function directly.

In `nn` api, you need to create an object of the loss class such as `criterion = nn.BCELoss()`

Thus, you can simply do:

```
def lossFunc(input, target):
   return F.binary_cross_entropy(torch.sigmoid(input),target)

input = torch.randn((3, 2), requires_grad=True)
target = torch.rand((3, 2), requires_grad=False)
loss = lossFunc(input,target)
```

Also, PyTorch provides [`nn.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) and [`F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits) that combines both sigmoid and binary cross-entropy.